# Convergence Rate

Tags: numerical-methods

So I have the polynomial $f(x)=8x^{4}-12x^{3}+6x^{2}-x$

And I was trying to find the convergence rate of the newton iteration when started close to the root r=0

My attempt:

Since $f'(r) \neq 0$ we have quadratic convergence with the convergence rate given $e_{i+1} \approx Me^{2}_{i}$

From Newton iteration I get that $x_{i+1}= \frac{6x^{2}_{i}}{6x_{i}-1}$ However I am not sure this is necessary..

So $f'(0)=-1$ and $f''(0)=0$ thus $M=0$ so the convergence rate is 0? is that possible?

Comment: The convergence rate...of what to what??

Comment: The convergence of newton iteration when started close to the root r=0

Comment: You should specify that in the question

Comment: okay I just did edit my question now

Comment: Does my calculation look right?

Comment: How do you get $f''(0)=0$? It is quite obvious that $f''(0)=2\cdot 6=12$. How did you get your iteration equation from $x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$?

Answer (score 1):

The Newton iteration is, for $x\approx0$,
\begin{align}
x_+=N_f(x) = x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
&=\frac{(64x^4−36x^3+12x^2-x)-(8x^4−12x^3+6x^2−x)}{64x^3−36x^2+12x-1}
\\[1em]
&=\frac{56x^4−24x^3+6x^2}{64x^3−36x^2+12x-1}
\\[1em]
&\approx-6x^2\frac{1-4x}{1-12x}\approx -6x^2.
\end{align}
Thus you find that $-6x_{i+1}\approx (-6x_i)^2$ or $$x_i\approx -\frac16(6x_0)^{\large 2^i}.$$ To get convergence you need $|x_0|\le\frac16-\varepsilon$ where the small $ε$ accounts for all the terms that were neglected in the derivation.